# Can I determine which properties are extern using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

After I get the properties of a class using the code below, is there a way to determine which properties are declared as `extern`?

```
SomeClass obj = new();

PropertyInfo[] properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I didn't realize that I should be using GetGetMethod first, and the following that other answer.

Comment: That's quite ok.  Remember... _we are **all** learning something, somewhere, sometime._ :)